# Simulating clicks of the mouse on a Shopify website

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm not a coder FYI.

What I'm trying to do is simulating clicks of the mouse on a Shopify website but within code.
So, as an example, you have a Shopify webpage with two drop down boxes and two buttons. I go to that page and click on those items and select whatever I select.

I want to be able to replicate those clicks within code so that the click of one button will replicate the same effect.

I hope that makes sense?

Is this possible?

Comment: If you tried can you provide your attempts?

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. `I want to be able to replicate those clicks within code` No. You don't. You want *that the click of one button will replicate the [effect of those clicks]*. Such has been called creating an *XY-problem*: Specifying/asking about *one particular mechanism* where what is useful is *one particular effect*. A hard lesson to learn, but it doesn't *need* to be the hard way.

Comment: @MERLIN havent tried, my coder couldnt figure it out. he just says a bunch of stuff to me tht makes me think he doesnt get it.

Comment: @greybeard ok, isnt tht what i said? the "code" i refer to, will be inside the button. so how does what i'm talking about get coded on shopify?

Comment: `[isn't that what I] said?` I see a communication problem. Chances are you get a solution for what your coder understands you want. And I don't see you describing that usefully: just tell what you want in the end, and let your coder bother with mechanisms. (Useless short answer: It isn't.)

Comment: nah he understood because we talked thru it with screenshare etc. here, im just typing a few words so its quite different. essentially, i want to be able to replicate clicks on a page with code. that code will sit inside a button. this end result stuff wont work because there is an issue with an app etc. i'm not going into it here because there is no point. if i know how to replicate the clicks, it will work.

Comment: @greybeard if i just tell him the end result, he might not think of my idea and do the wrong thing because he doesnt understand the full picture. which is exactly what happened. thats why, i'm just saying that i want to replicate clicks on a product page, using code.